# import from Excel adds a point to each number ...How to get rid of it?

Tags: excel

I import an excel file

```
c1  c2  c3
1   3   5
2   4   6


fp = NotebookDirectory[] <> "Book1.xls";

excelSheet = Import[fp] [[1]];
t1 = Grid[excelSheet, Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left,
  Background -> {None, {Gray, {White, LightGray}}}
```

The table shows each number with a "." at the end :(
How do I get rid of it?

```
c1  c2  c3
1.  3.  5.
2.  4.  6.
```

Thanx

Solution:

```
For[i = 1, i <= Length[excelSheet], i++,
  For[j = 1, j <= Length[excelSheet[[i]]], j++,
    If[NumericQ[excelSheet[[i, j]]],
      excelSheet[[i, j]] = Round[excelSheet[[i, j]]];
      ];
    ];
  ];
```

Comment: what should i do :( ?

Comment: do you expect me to read hundred of pages of text for such a simple problem ?!

Comment: Please read this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18485/131

Comment: read it . Didnt find anything usefull

Comment: I dont want the points to show in the table !

Comment: You can find it in the answer linked to by Yves. To make a long story short: use `Chop` or (not as good) `Floor`. I would use `Round`.

Comment: How to use Round ?

Comment: Please consider the following a friendly advice. Mathematica is a tough piece of software that demands a lot of effort to tame. Every experienced user already knows and accepts that. When you write _"do you expect me to read hundred of pages of text for such a simple problem ?"_ you should know that everybody out there have already done that, and don't consider it lost time. If you're not predisposed to invest a great deal of effort into Mathematica, don't even try. You'll feel discouraged too soon.

Comment: @TraceKira `excelSheet /. x_?NumericQ :> With[{r = Round[x]}, r /; r == x]` is more robust, or since it's Excel, `x_Real` instead of `x_?NumericQ`.  (You might not want to convert `6.4` to `6`.  This replacement rule will round to an integer only if the rounded value is equal to the original number.)

Answer (score 7):

Following discussion with WRI tech support, setting `Import`'s “Numeric” -> False has no effect on Excel files (.xls, .xlsx), but works when importing comma or tab delimited text files (.csv, .tsv).

WRI understands that "this could be very frustrating and inconvenient for you" and  apologizes for this but lacks the resources to fix.  So either:

(1) convert to csv (which by the way can also be exported via REST from Google gsheets)

(2) `Round[]` any `NumericQ` data after Import.

Comment: "but lacks the resources to fix." — have you tried telling WRI that you're doing _Tweetable data science of the computational world using the Internet of Things in Excel_? Maybe you'll get it fixed faster that way ;)

Comment: what does it means ? I cannot get rid of points ?

Comment: Anything that they don't intend to fix should be clearly documented as broken.