# Importing numbers from Excel

Tags: import, excel

I guess my problem is very simple but I could **not** find the solution by searching it.

I have a column in excel sheet (*Sheet1* in *Book1.xlsx*) including student numbers as the following.

```
Student ID
2014512060
2013512024
2013512028
```

When I import these numbers from *Excel* to *Mathematica* by

```
Import["C:\\Book1.xlsx", {"Sheets", "Sheet1"}]
```

what I get is the following output.

```
{{"Student ID"}, {2.01451*10^9}, {2.01351*10^9}, {2.01351*10^9}}
```

However, I want to get the following output.

```
{{"Student ID"}, {2014512060}, {2013512024}, {2013512028}}
```

**Question.** How can I get the exact student numbers?

Comment: Try in excel itself to change the column to be text instead of numerical. i.e. change the format of the column to text (in excel), save it, and try again the import to Mathematica.

Comment: @Nasser I first did what you have mentioned but it did not work.

Comment: This is caused by the frontend display truncating / displaying long (machine precision) numbers. You should be fine just `Rounding` or `Rationalize`ing your result. Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69470/131

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get data

```
x = Import["C:\\Book1.xlsx", {"Sheets", "Sheet1"}]
```

Recover the integers for instance like this

```
y = Floor /@ x[[1]] // Flatten

(* Out[202]= {Floor["Student ID"], 2014512060, 2013512024, 2013512028} *)
```

Just the data are then

```
z = Drop[y,1]

(* Out[203]= {2014512060, 2013512024, 2013512028} *)
```

**EDIT #1**

Taking up Yves Klett's remark I entered in Excel below the IDs the number 4,99999999999999 typing it in from the Keyboard.

The import gives

```
x1 = {{{"Student ID"}, {2.01451*10^9}, {2.01351*10^9}, {2.01351*10^9}, {5.}}}
```

Extracting the number in question

```
x2 = x1[[1, -1, 1]]

(* Out[218]= 5. *)
```

It looks at first sight that the decimal positions have been lost. But this is not the case:

```
{Floor[#], Round[#]} &@x[[1, -1, 1]]

(* Out[216]= {4, 5} *)
```

Floor[] shows that they might be still there. And FullForm[] shows them explicitly:

```
FullForm[x2]

(* Out[222]//FullForm= \!\(\*
TagBox[
StyleBox["4.99999999999999`",
ShowSpecialCharacters->False,
ShowStringCharacters->True,
NumberMarks->True],
FullForm]\) *)
```

Remark: I could not persuade N[] to exhibit the decimal places but I'm sure there are better methods than FullForm.

Comment: Would`Round` be more robust than `Floor` (in case of ever so slightly underrepresented numbers)?

Comment: @Yves Klett: I chose the brutal method Floor knowing that the source is integer numbers. But I don't understand your comment in brackets ...

Comment: Not sure if this is likely to happen with Excel import, but I was wondering about somthing like 5 being represented as 4.99999999999` or similar...

Comment: @Yves Klett: ok. BTW my extensive experience with Excel is that number formats is a feature "très special". For instance if there are leading zeroes which might very well appear in IDs.

Comment: So, does Excel always store numbers in a floating-point format? I was just wondering if this could be partly a problem of the import converter.

Comment: @Oleksandr R. I made the experiment: I can enter in an Excel cell (German language, therefore the comma instead of the dot) a = 4,123456789012340. But when I enter b = 4,123456789012341 is still appears as a. That is we have 15 significant digits, one before the dot and 14 after it. But I please explain to which problem of the import converter you are referring. Here we haven't encountered any.

Comment: Personally, I prefer to use 'IntegerPart'. It's clearer for me.

Comment: Well, if you enter 1234567890123(...) in an Excel worksheet, we get in the XML file the sequence 123456789012345, 1234567890123450, 1.23456789012345E+16 (although it looks different onscreen; we have trailing zeros and no scientific notation until 21 digits are reached). So even though it looks like Excel only keeps 14 digits of precision and probably uses double values internally (although why not 16 digits then?!), the contents of the file certainly doesn't suggest that these are necessarily supposed to be floating point values. Hence I'm asking why the import converter read them as such.

Answer (score 2):

A potential workaound is to use CSV as an intermediate format.

Some observations:

Excel does not internally distinguish an integer from a "real" integer. If you key in "1.00" it drops the decimal and stores "1"

Excel does not store integers with leading zeros *per se*, you can however apply a display format that specifies a fixed width left padded with zeros.

The largest integer excel can store is `999999999999999` (15 digits), but the default "general" format displays numbers larger then 11 digits in scientific notation.

If you export excel as csv what you get in the csv is the formatted number as you see displayed in the spreadsheet, that is by default numbers larger than 11 digits are rounded  and converted to scientific notation, ie:

```
     99999999999->99999999999
    999999999999->1E12   (no decimal)
    999999900000->1E12
    999999000000->9.99999E11
```

(you can get all 15 digits exported to CSV by fixing the display format in excel)

Numbers formatted to have lead zeros go in the csv with lead zeros.

Importing the csv gives you want you want (integers are integers), except leading zeros are dropped.

It appears to be a *feature* of the "xls" import filter to convert all numbers to reals,
and for the record the largest integer you evidently can import w/o loosing precision is 999999.  The xls import doesn't preserve at all any effect of excel display formatting.