# Why does Mathematica imports numbers from excel with "." after?

Tags: import, excel

I am importing data from Excel with the code
`Import["/Users/....\ xlsx"]`
and I what I get is a list such as
`{0., 6., 11., 14., 16., 21., 22., 25., 32., 33., 34., 46., 61., 70., \ 73., 78., 88., 89., 90., 95.}`

Why do the numbers have a dot after? This is causing some problems when I am trying to analyze the data, since `SameQ[61., 61]` gives false.

Any ideas on how to import the numerical values only?

Comment: I do not have excel, but isn't real numbers how excel internally store these as? any way, you could also always make these numbers exact after importing them. something like `= {0., 6., 11., 14., 16., 21., 22., 25., 32., 33., 34., 46., 61.,70.,  73., 78., 88., 89., 90., 95.};` then `SetAccuracy[L, Infinity]` which gives `{0, 6, 11, 14, 16, 21, 22, 25, 32, 33, 34, 46, 61, 70, 73, 78, 88, 
89, 90, 95}`  screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rvlX.png)

Comment: There seems to be similar question here also [importing-numbers-from-excel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71605/importing-numbers-from-excel)

Comment: This too `With[{r = Round[#]}, r + Chop[# - r]] & /@ Import["/Users/....\ xlsx"]`

Comment: Thank you for the answers! Round or Floor do what I wanted!!